# Corrupt or damaged file when uploading in s3 aws with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

When I upload a file in local environment, I have no problem with s3 and I download the file in aws without problem, but I upload the file in development environment in aws, the file is corrupted or does not open or opens empty, the parameters are the same in both cases

```
module.exports.handler = async event => {
  const body = multipart.parse(event, true)


  const { loan_id, document } = body
  const lang = event.headers?.Lang ? event.headers.Lang : event.headers?.lang

  try {
    const date = new Date()
    const stringDate = `${date.getFullYear()}${
      date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? `0${date.getMonth() + 1}` : date.getMonth() + 1
    }${date.getDay() < 10 ? `0${date.getDay()}` : date.getDay()}-${date.getHours()}${date.getMinutes()}`

    // Upload the file to S3
    const fullFileName = `${document.type}/${loan_id}-${stringDate}-${document.filename}`

    try {
      console.log('Uploading the file in S3 with key', fullFileName)
      
      //console.log(buf);
      var data = {
        Bucket: DOCUMENTS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: fullFileName, 
        Body: document.content,
        ContentType: document.ContentType
      }

      await s3
        .putObject(data)
        .promise()
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return serverlessResponse(HTTP_CODES.BAD_REQUEST, 'The file cannot be uploaded', err)
    }
}
```

[headers postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXgWB.png)

[Body form data postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJZ4U.png)

Comment: How do you upload from local?  And, what do you mean by "file is corrupted or does not open or opens empty"... do those happen randomly?